# Disable global repository and use just local repository in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am working with maven and there are all of project's dependencies in local repository (means .m2/repository), now, when i want to package project every time, it goes over internet and search over maven repositories to fetch dependencies (somewhere such as http://repo1.maven.org), although, I edit both of /m2/settings.xml and $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml files, and there isn't any global repository link in those, how can I disable maven to use global repository?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-o` option:

```
-o,--offline                           Work offline
```

In this case Maven won't connect any remote repositories.

Comment: it works, but it can't find dependency from local repo, for example, 'The POM for com.google.code:morphia:jar:0.99 is missing, no dependency information available', but there is available in local repo (.m2/repository/com/google/code/morphia/0.99/)

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven as offline mode.

mvn -o install

Comment: can you rename morphia/0.99/ in your local repo. Then, run without -o option. Then again with -o option.